Firefox doesn't save changes made in about:config
I have a Ubuntu (Unity) 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) installation which distributes firefox via snap.
The problem im facing is, that whatever changes i made in about:config, after a restart of firefox the changes i made are gone.
For example, i disabled the tab preview (browser.tabs.hoverPreview.enabled):

After closing, and opening firefox, the value is again "true".
Is this a bug in firefox or a problem with snap?

I had the same problem, and it turned out my browser had a study turned on for the feature that overrode the about:config setting.
If the same is the case for you you can go to about:studies and remove Tab Hover Preview Release Rollout.

wtf?! that was it! If you're ever in Germany, near Nuremberg, I'll buy you a beer!

First what comes to mind is that you have permissions issue - I just tested "browser.tabs.hoverPreview.enabled" on my FF (Rocky 8.10 not Ubuntu though) - it's not a protected preference, I succesfuly changed it back and forth a few times.
My advice:

Go to about:profiles, open "Root directory" of your active profile and check your writing privileges for it, including all the files and directory itself. Most important in your case would be prefs.js file.

Open the file and look for browser.tabs.hoverPreview.enabled. Here's how it looks in my file:


If you can't see obvious privileges problem try adding the entry manually (with FF closed!), save, check FF, close, change the value in file, check FF.



If this doesn't help check if any of the following exists:

%Firefox installation directory%/distribution/policies.json
Documentation
%Firefox installation directory%/firefox.cfg and defaults/pref/autoconfig.js
Documentation
%active FF profile directory%/user.js

If any one of those exists - it overrides prefs.js

Closed FF, made the changes, added user_pref("browser.tabs.cardPreview.showThumbnails", false); (in ~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/dzburjya.default/prefs.js) saved & started. But nothing changed. In about:config its still set to true. File permissions are "rw" only to my user. After opening the file "prefs.js" again, the entry/changes i made are gone. Did you install FF via snap?

And after you close FF and check the file - does the value stay like you saved it earlier or is it changed to true like seen in about:config ?

The entry is not there in the prefs.js after i close FF. Its removed when i added it. The prefs.js is completely overriden.

@Marc I edited my answer, check 3 added places

Edited user.js as well, and same result. Set browser.tabs.cardPreview.enabled to false in user.js but FF still displays Thumbnails & about:config says also "enabled". Event if in the user.js its set to false. No matter what/where i set browser.tabs.cardPreview.enabled its always the same result. After a FF restart, its enabled...

@Marc What about policies.json and autoconfig.js ? If I remember correctly both have higher priority than user.js, which has higher priority than prefs.js (not 100% sure).

There is no policies.json or autoconfig.js. What i find strange, on my workstation (also installed ff via snap) i could turn it off. Same distro, same version, same installation procedure.

Try creating a new profile, restarting FF and then trying to change the setting.

New profile did also not work. No clue whats the different between my notebook & workstation. But thanks :)

Well, as a last resort - try complete reinstallation? I'm genuinely curious wth is going on there :)
